# how to store a float value on a neo4django model

Tags: python, django, floating-point, neo4j, neo4django

I am writing an app using `django 1.4.5` and `neo4django` (`github` version). I have created a model

e.g.

```
class FloatValues(models.NodeModel):
    a_float_value = models.StringProperty()
```

It looks like there is no a `float` property in `neo4django`, so I am thinking that I should either use a `StringProperty` or use an `IntArrayProperty`.

What is the best way to store a `float` value? (besides implementing a `FloatProperty`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to go with- implementing a `FloatProperty` :) Really, it should already be in neo4django. Here's a simple implementation that doesn't support indexing.

```
class FloatProperty(Property):
    def get_default(self):
        return 0.0

    def to_neo(self, value):
        return float(value)
```

I'll raise an issue and try to get a real implementation out for the next release.